# Specify to Stack which version of Happy to use

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, happy

I'm running up against [a bug](https://github.com/simonmar/happy/issues/35) in the latest version of Happy (1.19.5). How do I tell stack to go look for an even newer version of Happy (1.19.6) found only at the git repo? Right now, I'm letting stack manage everything; the only reference to Happy is in my cabal file. The relevant section is:

```
...

library:
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  build-tools:         alex, happy

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following in your `stack.yaml` file to have a particular package treated as a dependency package:

```
packages:
- location: .
- location:
    git: git@github.com:orgname/project_name
    commit: <commitid>
  extra-dep: true
```

Replace with the proper git url and commit id for referencing the happy project. You can read more information about that [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/yaml_configuration.md#local-dependency-packages-extra-dep).

Comment: I may be wrong, but aren't `happy` and `alex` special in this regard? Or are they treated as any other package? Note this isn't the `build-depends` section...

Comment: @Alec Ah, I was under the impression it was under `build-depends` section. This thread may help you: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/782#issuecomment-131417028 . Let us know how it goes.